# how to take into account '-' in an argument in argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I have a very generic question regarding argument parsing in `argparse`.
I have a requirement wherein the arguments will be containing '-' in the beginning.
Please can someone help me how to take this into account?

e.g.

```
sample.py -Defines -test_1
```

I want `-test_1` to be accepted as an argument parameter for `-Defines` and not treated as a separate argument.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#arguments-containing

Comment: @DainDwarf: that doesn't tell us anything about *values for optional parameters*.